Monoid structure on polynomial quotient ring / quotient fields
Let $\mathbb F$ be a field and let $P\in\mathbb F[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial.  Write $\mathbb F'=\mathbb F[X]/P$, and note that this is also a field.
Let $P'\in\mathbb F[X]$ be any polynomial and write $\langle P'\rangle \in \mathbb F'$ for the equivalence class of $P'$ in $\mathbb F'$, i.e. $\langle P'\rangle$ is the set of all polynomials in $\mathbb F[X]$ that are equal to $P'$ modulo $P$ in $\mathbb F[X]$.
It seems to me that this gives $\mathbb F'$ a monoid structure (a set with an associative composition and identity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) given by
$$
\langle P'\rangle \circ \langle P''\rangle = \langle P'(P'')\rangle.
$$
(Above, $P'(P'')$ denotes the polynomial obtained by replacing $X$ by $P''$ in $P'$; e.g. if $P'=X+1$ and $P''=X^2+1$ then $P'(P'')=X^2+2$.)
The identity of this monoid is just $\langle X\rangle$, of course.
If the above is correct then presumably this monoid structure has been studied.  Can anyone provide references, or point out where I have made an error?  Thank you.

I'm not sure your composition is even well-defined. In general the equivalence relation imposed by the ideal fails to be a congruence with respect to composition, so that the monoid structure doesn't survive the quotient.

(E.g. $P(x) = x^2+x+1$ over $\Bbb F_2$: the "monoid multiplication" by $x^2 + 1$ is not the identity map.)
